# Delete a line of unwanted pixels

Tags: rendering, animation

What could be the cause of a line of pixels highlighted in the image below? All positions should match perfectly. It seems to be at certain angles, but it's also in the animation render.

[image: The line of the pixels]

Here are block positions.

[image: Position of the block 1]
[image: Position of the block2]

Comment: In OpenGL. When two polygons have same Z-buffer value (distance from camera) for a pixel then it's not guaranteed that correct polygon will be displayed for that pixel. First try separating the faces by a micrometer. It should tell your rendering engine what to display in the front. If that doesn't help combine your cubes manually into a single mesh.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I appreciate your effort. Unfortunately, non of these procedures helped me. :/

Comment: Could you provide a blend file with this exact problem?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au_FVbUQmmZdkiVADRekb7GLQzpK?e=iXQehm

Comment: first deactivate the Subsruf otherwise your shape won't display correctly. These two cubes are separate, it looks like even if you create additional edge loops for the vertical one and snap their vertices you'll still have this thin line, you can either recreate this shape with one unique object and some extrusions, or snap the vertices and delete the faces that are overlapping

Comment: Thank you for the answer. None of these cubes have a Subdivision Surface modifier applied. Yes, they are separated - as you can see on the pictures above. Well, I can not snap these vertices together because of the animation. There is really no solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining cubes together so they are touching is not the best flow to make a mesh.
If my suggested fixes didn't help I suggest using Extrude tool when creating a single more complicated mesh.

Select a face

[image: Cube]

Then use combination `E` `Z` `2` to extrude it up by 2 units

[image: Extruded cube]

Select the side face

[image: Side face selected]

And type `E` `Y` `-5`

[image: Angle]

You will end up with a single object with a single mesh (and no islands) that renders correctly.

[image: Perfection]

When animating simply use this mesh for static shots, and when things need to move just hide it, and use your separated meshes.

**EDIT:**

Issue seems to be visible only in Eevee rendering engine.

Eevee

[image: Eevee]

Cycles

[image: Cycles]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, I really appreciate your help, Filip. The point is, I created the entire animation using scaling. In order to use this method, I would have to start almost completely again. It would take me a long time. But if there is really no solution, I will use this method and accept this answer.

Comment: @Nogard Seems like issue is almost invisible in cycles.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is actually the solution! Sure, I have to wait more to get such a great looking animation from Cycles without any noise, but I do not have to remake whole animation. Perfect!